# When does whitespace matter in HTML?

Tags: html, whitespace

## [example 1](http://jsfiddle.net/g5FBv/)

```
<div><button>one</button><button>two</button></div>

<div>
    <button>one</button>
    <button>two</button>
</div>
​
```

In the first div there is no space between the two buttons, in the second, there is.

Now let's consider another example:

## [example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/g5FBv/1/)

```
<div>a</div>
<div> b</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

There is no space before that `b`.

## example 3

```
a<b> bold</b> man
```

Now the whitespace before `bold` *is* significant

## example 4

```
a <b> bold</b> man
```

Now only one of the spaces (after the "a" or before "bold") is significant.

## question

What are the exact rules behind when whitespace is stripped or collapsed?

Comment: Is the question only concerned with how HTML is displayed in the browser?  Or is it also about the spec, or about how HTML parsing APIs deal with whitespace?

Comment: @MattFenwick: Mostly concerned with how the browser renders it. I'm converting HTML into another language and I want it to look more or less the same.

Comment: I removed my answer as it was an over-simplification. Jukka K. Korpela and Alohci have addressed the more complicated parts.

Answer (score 17):

The reality is somewhat complicated. There are two parts

1. What the parsing does.
2. What the rendering does.

The parsing actually removes very little white space whilst parsing text (as opposed to markup). It will [remove an initial line feed character at the start of `<textarea>` and `<pre>` elements](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/syntax.html#element-restrictions) and also on the invalid `<listing>` element, but that's about it.

Jukka refers to the HTML 4.01 section [B.3.1 Line breaks](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/appendix/notes.html#h-B.3.1) saying that "a line break immediately following a start tag must be ignored, as must a line break immediately before an end tag" but that is in a non-normative appendix and browsers do not follow it except for the three elements mentioned above.

That can be demonstrated using Jukka's example [here](http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/js/live-dom-viewer/?%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%0A%3Cdiv%3E%0A%3Cbutton%3Eone%3C%2Fbutton%3E%0A%3Cbutton%3Etwo%3C%2Fbutton%3E%0A%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A) on line breaks with no spaces . Note the `#text:` nodes around the button elmeents in the tree display, and that if the line breaks are removed, the '#text:` nodes no longer appear.

We can also see that the rule is not applied by using that first example from the specification [here](http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/js/live-dom-viewer/?%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%0A%3Cstyle%3E%0Ap%20%7B%20white-space%3Apre%3B%20background-color%3A%20yellow%3B%20%7D%0A%3C%2Fstyle%3E%0A%0A%3CP%3EThomas%20is%20watching%20TV.%3C%2FP%3E%0A%0A%3CP%3E%0AThomas%20is%20watching%20TV.%0A%3C%2FP%3E%0A%0A).  By adding `display:pre` it's clear that the line breaks are not exactly ignored but that the rendering the two examples the same is merely a property of the default white-space handling being `white-space:normal`

Which brings us to the relevant spec, which is [16.6.1 The 'white-space' processing model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#white-space-model) in the CSS spec. This covers the systematic rules to be applied to the text characters for each of the white-space setting values.

Comment: Appendix B of HTML 4.01 specification is indeed informative, but as it says: “all requirements in this section appear elsewhere in the specification”. The basic conformance clause says that HTML documents are SGML documents, and the principle on ignoring line breaks in certain conditions is part of the SGML standard, hence normative. But HTML was never actually implemented as an SGML application; and this part, too, was almost exclusively ignored by browser vendors.

Answer (score 7):

HTML collapses serial whitespaces to a single whitespace, but doesn't eliminate it. A newline is a whitespace, therefore a space.

It's not just leading/trailing - serial whitespace within an element is rendered as single whitespace as well. These will render identically:

```
<div>   a   b   </div>
<div> a b </div>
<div>a b</div>
```

Comment: Collapsing is pretty straight-forward, it's the trimming that concerns me :)

Comment: Actually, collapsing is a bit more complicated than that. Consecutive/serial whitespace across inline elements is also collapsed.

Comment: while your example is correct, it deals with the simplest case and therefore does not address the question. See Example 3 and 4 in the question.

Answer (score 7):

A full answer to the question “When does whitespace matter in HTML?” would be rather long and detailed and would need to discuss things like whitespace between attribute specifications and elements with special rules like `textarea`. But the address what seems to be the primary concern:

Whitespace between tags generally creates anonymous text nodes. Whitespace inside leaf elements (elements not containing other elements) constitutes part of the text content of the element.

There are few fixed rules for rendering, but browsers generally ignore leading and trailing whitespace within an element’s text content.

If there is whitespace between elements that are rendered inline (such as `button` elements by default), it normally acts as a separator equivalent to one space.

However, whitespace consisting of one line break is ignored, [by specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/appendix/notes.html#h-B.3.1) <del>and usually in browser practice,</del> when it immediately follows a start tag or precedes an end tag. So

```
<div>
<button>one</button>
<button>two</button>
</div>
```

would be treated as if the line breaks were not there. But when spaces are used, as in

```
<div>
  <button>one</button>
  <button>two</button>
</div>
```

then there are anonymous text nodes before the first `button` element and between the two `button` elements. Normally only the latter matters, and it acts like a normal word space.

**Update:** As a comment below and Alohci’s answer point out, this old (HTML 4.01) principle has mostly not been implemented in browsers and has mostly been removed in HTML5. So in most cases, a line break between elements creates a text node, containing a line break character, which is treated as equivalent to a space.

Comment: Your statement and two examples about one line break being ignored is not correct for recent versions of Chrome, Firefox, or Opera, or in IE8 or IE10: http://jsbin.com/eKAzUfI/1 ([source](http://jsbin.com/eKAzUfI/1/edit)). Interestingly, it *is* correct for IE6 (!) and IE9. I didn't test IE7. I tested with a standalone file as well just in case it was something in JSBin's default CSS, but the results were the same.

Comment: I stand corrected and will make some corrections to my answer (won’t delete it though, since some points are valid and the incorrect points are referenced in another answer).