# Generating checkbox using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I wrote this JavaScript code to generate check boxes :

```
ques = document.getElementById("question");
var q = ques.appendChild(document.createElement("ol"));
q.appendChild(document.createTextNode(allQuestions[0].question));
var list = ques.appendChild(document.createElement("ul"));
for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        var option = list.appendChild(document.createElement("input"));
        option.type = "checkbox" ;
        list.appendChild(document.createTextNode(allQuestions[0].choices[i]));
        list.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    }
```

This results in following output :

[image]

and the generated HTML is :

```
<input type="checkbox">
David Cameron
<br>
<input type="checkbox">
Gordon Brown
<br>
<input type="checkbox">
Winston Churchill
<br>
<input type="checkbox">
Tony Blair
<br>
</ul>
```

The output looks fine but I think the resulted HTML is not correct. It should be like :

```
<input type="checkbox" >David Cameron<br>
```

May be both are same and may be different. I am not sure. Can anyone tell me the difference ? 
Kindly also suggest improvements in my code too, if there is some better method to generate the checkboxes.

**EDIT : My question is not about whitespaces. In the HTML my code generates the checkbox and the text in front of it is not connected. I feel they should be binded somewhat as the check box is for the text. Is their any possible method to relate to the text to the checkbox ?**

Comment: In your case there's no difference. There might be a problem if those checkboxes were set to be display: inline-block;

Comment: possible duplicate of [When does whitespace matter in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12863588/when-does-whitespace-matter-in-html)

Comment: The very first example in the suggested duplicate covers the difference between having elements on the same line versus on their own lines. In your case one element is a text node rather than a bracketed element, but it's still the same question.

Comment: @sphanley : Kindly try to understand what my question is.  I don't have doubt about whitespaces. I feel the text in front of the checkbox should relate to the checkbox. In my code both are child of "ul" tag but not related to each other. So I am asking is the code is good or is there some better way to do the same thing ?

Comment: They're not "related to each other" whether they're on the same line or not. If you just have an input and a text node, they're two elements that are just being rendered next to each other, one input and one text node, and whether there's any difference between putting them on one line or on separate lines is addressed in the question I linked to. You're getting hung up on the idea that putting them on the same line somehow "associates" them, but that isn't true. This is exactly the same as example 1 in the linked question, just one of the elements is a text node.

Comment: I think what you're trying to get across is that you're really asking if this is the correct way to create labels for checkboxes. If so, you would do well to edit your post and de-emphasize the fact that the elements aren't all on one line, and emphasize that you just want to know if you're labeling the checkboxes in the best way. Otherwise it comes across as a duplicate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common way to relate the check box to it's text is the use of `label` and the `for` attribute :

```
<input type="checkbox" id="foo" value="David Cameron">
<label for="foo">David Cameron</label>
```

Note the `value` attribute which has to be filled with your text or anything which relates to it such as the text's `id` in your DB.

Comment: So I should use label and then createTextNode to insert the text ?

Comment: Yes, that's the clean way to do it :). You could also append your label and then insert your text into it with `insertHTML` but within a `for` loop it has perfomance issues so `createTextNode` is better.