# Regex efficiency, better way to select text among html

Tags: javascript, html, regex, dom, google-chrome-extension

This is about a Chrome Extension.

Suppose a user select any text on a page, then clicks a button to save it. Via window.getSelection() I can get that text without the underlying html markup.

I store that text. For demo purposes, let's say the text is:

"**John was much more likely to buy if he knew the price beforehand**"

The next time the user visits the page, I want to find that text on the page. The issue is, the html for that text is actually:

```
<b>John was much more likely to buy if he knew the price <span class="italic">beforehand</span></b>
```

The second issue is that this system needs to work even if the selection is dirty, i.e. it starts/ends mid DOM node.

What I've build is bit of a fat solution, so I am curious how I can make it more efficient and/or smaller. This is the whole thing:

```
text.split("").map(function(el, i, arr){
   if(specials.includes(el)){
      return "\\"+el;
   } 
   return el;
})
.join("(?:\\s*<[^>]+>\\s*)*\\s*");
```

where text is the saved text and specials is

```
var specials = [
  '/', '.', '*', '+', '?', '|',
  '(', ')', '[', ']', '{', '}', '\\'
];
```

The process is:

1. Split text into single characters
2. For each character, check if it's a special char and if so, prepend it with \
3. Join all letters together with regEx that check if there's any whitespace or html tags inbetween

My question is, can it be done in a better way? I get the "bruteforcing" feeling with this solution and I don't know if it would actually cause lag on larger sites/selection texts.

Plus, it doesn't work for SPAs where text may update a bit after the DOM is ready.

Thank you for any input.

EDIT:

So initially I was using [mark.js](https://github.com/julmot/mark.js/), which doesn't handle this at all, but not 12 hours after I posted this question the maintainer release v8.0.0 that uses NodeList and handles my use case. The feature is "acrossElements", located [here](https://github.com/julmot/mark.js/blob/8.0.0/dist/mark.js#L281).

Answer (score 1):

1. [create a Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createRange) object
2. set it so that it spans the entire document from start to end
3. check if the string of interest is in its `toString()`
4. clone range twice
5. apply [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) by moving the start/end points of the subranges into roughly their midpoint. this can be approximated by finding the first descendant with > 1 child nodes and then splitting the child list
6. goto 3

this should roughly take `n log m` steps where n is the document text length and m the number of nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Build the entire text representation of the document manually from each node with `nodeType` of `Node.TEXT_NODE`, saving the node reference and its text's start/end positions relative to the overall string in an array. Do it just once as DOM is slow, and you might want to search for multiple strings. Otherwise the other answer might be much faster (without actual benchmarks it's a moot point).

Apply [HTML whitespace coalescing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12865760/3959875) rules.
Otherwise you'll end up with huge spans of spaces and newline characters.
For example, `Range.toString()` doesn't strip them, meaning you'd have to convert your string to a RegExp with `[\s\n\r]+` instead of spaces and all other special characters like {}()[]|^$*.?+ escaped.

Anyway, it'd be wise to use the converted RegExp on `document.body.textContent` before proceeding (easy to implement, many examples on the net, thus not included below).

A simplified implementation for plain-string search follows.

```js
function TextMap(baseElement) {
    this.baseElement = baseElement || document.body;

    var textArray = [], textNodes = [], textLen = 0, collapseSpace = true;
    var walker = document.createTreeWalker(this.baseElement, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT);

    while (walker.nextNode()) {
        var node = walker.currentNode;
        var nodeText = node.textContent;
        var parentName = node.parentNode.localName;

        if (parentName==='noscript' || parentName==='script' || parentName==='style') {
            continue;
        }
        if (parentName==='textarea' || parentName==='pre') {
            nodeText = nodeText.replace(/^(\r\n|[\r\n])/, '');
            collapseSpace = false;
        } else {
            nodeText = nodeText.replace(/^[\s\r\n]+/, collapseSpace ? '' : ' ')
                               .replace(/[\s\r\n]+$/, ' ');
            collapseSpace = nodeText.endsWith(' ');
        }

        if (nodeText) {
            var len = nodeText.length;
            textArray.push(nodeText);
            textNodes.push({
                node: node,
                start: textLen,
                end: textLen + len - 1,
            });
            textLen += len;
        }
    }

    this.text = textArray.join('');
    this.nodeMap = textNodes;
}

TextMap.prototype.indexOf = function(str) {
    var pos = this.text.indexOf(str);
    if (pos < 0) {
        return [];
    }
    var index1 = this.bisectLeft(pos);
    var index2 = this.bisectRight(pos + str.length - 1, index1);
    return this.nodeMap.slice(index1, index2 + 1)
                       .map(function(info) { return info.node });
}

TextMap.prototype.bisect =
TextMap.prototype.bisectLeft = function(pos) {
    var a = 0, b = this.nodeMap.length - 1;
    while (a < b - 1) {
        var c = (a + b) / 2 |0;
        if (this.nodeMap[c].start > pos) {
            b = c;
        } else {
            a = c;
        }
    }
    return this.nodeMap[b].start > pos ? a : b;
}

TextMap.prototype.bisectRight = function(pos, startIndex) {
    var a = startIndex |0, b = this.nodeMap.length - 1;
    while (a < b - 1) {
        var c = (a + b) / 2 |0;
        if (this.nodeMap[c].end > pos) {
            b = c;
        } else {
            a = c;
        }
    }
    return this.nodeMap[a].end >= pos ? a : b;
}
```

Usage:

```js
var textNodes = new TextMap().indexOf('<span class="italic">');
```

When executed on this question's page:

> [text, text, text, text, text, text]

Those are text nodes, so to access corresponding DOM elements use the standard `.parentNode`:

```js
var textElements = textNodes.map(function(n) { return n.parentNode });
```

> Array[6]
>     0: span.tag
>     1: span.pln
>     2: span.atn
>     3: span.pun
>     4: span.atv
>     5: span.tag

Comment: The dom traversal seems complicated considering the existence of the `TreeWalker` API or xpath expressions which could get you all text nodes.

Comment: XPath for text nodes is also very slow in DOM.

Comment: callback? there are no callbacks involved.

Comment: well, it mostly avoids the need for recursion, so you can write it as a straight-forward loop

Comment: Thanks again, it turned out to be just as fast (5-10 ms on this page) and allowed unindenting the code.

Comment: Ok, huge help, thanks! What has now happened is that a library I'm using has _just_ had an update and can now handle this functionality natively, without me writing regex for it. I'm still grateful for the answers but a bit confused which one to accept, as I won't be using either implementation... Any suggestions?

Comment: Actually, you should add an answer of your own describing that other solution you're using.