# How to recognize special chars?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to display a paragraph inside the HTML `<div>` tag.

How can I recognize those special formatting characters and display the paragraph as intended?

I attempted within `render() { return( <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: paragraph}}/> )}`, but it still does not recognize the special formatting characters and just displays the paragraph in one block/ in lines, without any formatting.

Thank you and will be sure to vote up the answer and accept it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `pre` (preformatted) tag instead?

```
<pre>{paragraph}</pre>
```

This is pretty much the canonical usage for the `<pre>` tag, as [HTML ignores most whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12863588/when-does-whitespace-matter-in-html).

Alternatively, you could add the `white-space: pre` rule to your `<div>`.

```
<div style={{ whiteSpace: 'pre' }}>{paragraph}</div>
```

This will have the same effect, but is arguably less semantic HTML.