# How to properly display line breaks in asp GridView BoundField without turning HTML encoding off

Tags: html, asp.net, gridview, web, frontend

I need to show line breaks in the contents of the asp BoundField in an asp GridView. I originally had \r\n, but the page completely ignored this line breaking. The second thing I did was replace my line breaks with  in the string, but the page just showed the literal text "" wherever I had this in the string. The last thing i tried technically worked, and I achieved this by putting  in my string for the field with HTML encoding for the element set to "false". The problem I have with this solution is that I heard this can cause security concerns. How do I have line breaks in these fields without setting HTML encoding to false.

Comment: A line break in html is `<br/>`, not `\r\n`.

Comment: but my site shows it literally as  "<br />" rather than a break unless i have HTML encode=false

Comment: Can you show the code from the GridView?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, HTML treats line breaks, tabs and spaces as common white-space, and collapses multiple white-space characters into a single space for rendering.  So including line breaks in your HTML will not usually impact the way the text is rendered in the browser.  For some more information and background on this topic I refer you to this previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12863588/when-does-whitespace-matter-in-html), which has some very informative comments.

However, if you want line breaks in your text to be rendered as line breaks in the browser, you can achieve this in pure CSS without turning HTML encoding off or introducing any security concerns.  The [white-space CSS property](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/white-space) is standard and has been supported by all major browsers for a long time, and enables you to instruct the browser to render line breaks as is.

Changing the HTML generated by ASP.Net `GridView` to include CSS styling can be achieved by use of the [`<ItemStyle>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.itemstyle(v=vs.110).aspx) tag as demonstrated below:

```
<style>
    .preformatted 
    {
        white-space: pre-line;
    }
</style>

<asp:GridView runat="server" ...>
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField ...>
            <ItemStyle CssClass="preformatted"/>
        </asp:BoundField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Instead of using `white-space: pre-line;` you could also try `white-space: pre;`, but this takes away the browser's ability to flow the text to fit the available space, so may result in your grid column becoming too wide if your text does not contain sufficient line breaks.

Comment: This does work. Before I accept your answer can you explain why this works? Why would it not work without this? I have tried other types of line breaks (<br />) so why does the aspx need this extra instruction to do what it should do by default?

Comment: Hi @adam that's a good point. I've modified my answer to include a link to a specific question that covers the treatment of white-space.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a search and replace in the `RowDataBound` event of the GridView.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //check if the row is a datarow
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //find the boundfield cell
        string cellValue = e.Row.Cells[0].Text;

        //replace the encoded <br> with a real one and put the string back
        e.Row.Cells[0].Text = cellValue.Replace("&lt;br /&gt;", "<br />");
    }
}
```

You may need to extend the replace to include more `br` types, like `<br>`, `<br/>`, `<BR>` etc.

Answer (score 0):

The question specifically said Bound fields, however, I had a similar need for gridview template fields and I found using:

```
        style="white-space: pre-wrap;"
```

...worked for what I needed (and that option might help some for Bound-fields too).
e.g.

```
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Message" SortExpression="CommittedMessage">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox7" runat="server" 
                        Text='<%# Bind("CommittedMessage") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" 
                        ForeColor='<%# System.Drawing.Color.FromName(Eval("WarningForeColour").ToString()) %>'
                        style="white-space: pre-wrap;"
                        Text='<%# Bind("CommittedMessage") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <ItemStyle Font-Names="9px" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
```