# Using preg_replace to put all html tags within paragraph on new lines

Tags: php, html, preg-replace

I am using `preg_replace` to make all html tags within paragraph blocks go on a new line, e.g. `<strong></strong>` or `<a></a>`. However, it is causing an extra whitespace at the end of any replaced tags.

Here is the code:

```
$text = preg_replace('/\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+>/', "$0\n", $text);
```

Here is an example of the returned html output within an inspector tool:

```
<p>
  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent "
  <strong>faucibus ut turpis </strong>
  <a href="#" target="_blank">eu consequat</a>
  " . Etiam fermentum nisi id massa ultricies, non pretium libero tempus.
</p>
```

As you can see, this adds in the space after the hyperlink and before the full stop.

Comment: It means the whitespace has already been there, or you have another line of code that inserts spaces before `.`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - I don't think so. If I comment out this bit of code, then it all looks normal again. Note - this is also using a page editor CMS system.

Comment: `\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+>` does not match any whitespace. `$0\n` does not introduce any whitespace except an LF char. The space is not there due to that line you showed - period.

Comment: This is what I thought - but then just can't understand how the extra space is no longer shown if comment out just this line of code.

Comment: Line feed is whitespace, which is what the inspector is showing

Comment: Instead of `\n` use the regular `<br>` if you're outputting HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In html, a newline is whitespace. Your code is working - it inserts a newline (which is whitespace) after each tag.

The inspector doesn't distinguish what kind of whitespace is in the html, since they're all equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

As others have already commented, the whitespace is there because you insert it with the "\n" character (perhaps [basically this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12863646/367456)).

Semantically inside a paragraph (in HTML you can start a paragraph with the `<p>` tag, the closing tag is optional) you may want the newline "\n" to format the source but you may not want it to add to the (visible) whitespace.

If the original source is

```
 <a href="#" target="_blank">eu consequat</a>" . Etiam fermentum nisi id massa ultricies, non pretium libero tempus.
```

the production with your regex results in adding the newline and henceforth whitespace after the closing `</a>` tag. It becomes visible because there was no whitespace before.

If you include any non-whitespace before inserting the newline "\n" therefore, you can preserve the whitespace handling as multiple whitespace characters are displayed as one space when the HTML is rendered in a browser.

This may come closer to what you intend for the source production:

```php
$text = preg_replace('/\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+>\S*/', "$0\n", $text);
```

`\S` is any non-whitespace character (the opposite of `\s`, mind the US-ASCII encoding, which IIRC should suffice for HTML encoded in UTF-8 as well, otherwise study the PCRE_UTF8 and PCRE_UCP verbs);

and should lead to a production like:

```
  <a href="#" target="_blank">eu consequat</a>"
  . Etiam fermentum nisi id massa ultricies, non pretium libero tempus.
```

As after the quote there was whitespace earlier and the link ends directly at the double-quotation-mark, the HTML rendering should not be effected regarding whitespace as no new whitespace segment has been introduced.

However take this with a grain of salt, this is really on the micro level of the some characters here.

The rules how whitespace is treated are likely simplified in my answer and the specification of whitespace in HTML and implementations in Browsers add up to it:

- [When does whitespace matter in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12863588/367456)